# How to parse non-english text date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have date in the text format like:

```
6 weeks ago, 2012 April 18 15:08:18
13 weeks ago, 2012 March 01 17:33:52
```

The main problem is that this texts are really in Russian, so instead of `weeks ago` there is the same text in Russian. And the same is with months (looks like I should create some dictionary of possible values).

I don't know how to start. Should I use regular expressions? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not Russian, but Polish:

```
var dateStr = "6 tygodni temu, 2012 kwiecień 18 15:08:18"
```

Firefox has no problems in extracting Unicode characters (quick & dirty regular expression):

```
var regex = /(\d+) ty.* temu, (\d+) (.*) (\d+) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/
```

Parsing:

```
var result = dateStr.match(regex);
```

The `result` is:

```
[
  "6 tygodni temu, 2012 kwiecień 18 15:08:18",
  "6",
  "2012",
  "kwiecień",
  "18", 
  "15",
  "08",
  "18"
]
```

I don't know Russian, but you might need to do some extra linguistic work. E.g. in Polish I have "*1 tydzień*" but "*2 tygodnie*" and even "*5 tygodni*" (mind the different form).

Comment: Thanks! I've created array of Russian month names, replaced it in the string first and then parsed with regex.